# Multiline(in one paragraph) pattern replace use awk or sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

````
$cat test.txt

blablabla
```{r}
blabla
```

blablabla
blablabla
blablabla

```{r}
blablabla
blablabla
imname <- "FIGNAME1"
saveflag <- savepdf(imname)

```

```{r}
blablabla
blablabla
imname <- "FIGNAME2"
saveflag <- savepdf(imname)
```

blablabla
````

I want to replace:

```
\`\`\`{r}** to **\`\`\`{r figname:FIGNAME1}**, where **FIGNAME1** comes from the line start with **imname**, can be match by **imname.\*".\*"**.
```

Expected output:

````
blablabla
```{r}
blabla
```

blablabla
blablabla
blablabla

```{r figname:FIGNAME1}
blablabla
blablabla
imname <- "FIGNAME1"
saveflag <- savepdf(imname)

```

```{r figname:FIGNAME2}
blablabla
blablabla
imname <- "FIGNAME2"
saveflag <- savepdf(imname)
```

blablabla
````

I tried `sed` but no success.

````
sed -e '/\`\`\`.*r/{:a;N;/^$/p;/imname.*".*"/!{$!ba};s/\`\`\`.*r\(.*imname.*\)"\(.*\)"/```{r figname:\2\1"\2"/}' test.txt
````

Comment: What of sed did you try?

Comment: The sed script match the pattern across over paragraph as well, which is not expect.

Comment: Any reason you can't use Perl?  You can redefine line-end and get some nice multi-line matching with `perl -p0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed '
    /{r}/{                                  #if line consist {r}
        :1                                  #mark No.1
        $!{                                 #if not last line:
            N                               #append next line
            /\n\n/!b1                       #if not empty line
        }                                   #+return to mark No.1
    }     #=collect one paragraph(from {r} to empty line) 
    s/}.*imname <- "\([^"]*\)/ figname:\1&/ #add text after "imname" to "r"
' test.txt
```

Comment: Thank you.
It works very well.
Could you please explan little bit on your code?

Comment: @MingSu See commented.